# Writing out database table to xml

Tags: php, xml, database, sqlite

Firstly, I do not want an alternative code, I only want help to make this work. 
Using the code below I want to write out the data from the database table to the xml file but I am only getting the "john" and "123" with out the correct xml tags and my second foreach() doesnt work, but the first foreach() to display the table works.

```
<?php

$dbhandle = sqlite_popen("propertydb", 0666, $err_msg);
if(!$dbhandle) die("Could not open the database");

$query = "CREATE TABLE property(pCode VARCHAR(8), price VARCHAR(6), 
iFile VARCHAR(15),          visits VARCHAR(3))";
if(!sqlite_query($dbhandle, $query)){ echo "table not created (maybe already
created)";
} 

$query = sqlite_query($dbhandle, 'SELECT * FROM property');  
$result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);  

foreach ($result as $arow) {
echo '<br> Postcode:  ' . $arow['pCode'] . '  Price:  ' . $arow['price'] . 
' Image  File:  ' . $arow['iFile'] . ' Visits:  ' . $arow['visits'];
}

$outfilepointer = fopen("property.xml","w");
$outtext = "<estateagent> \n";
$outtext .= "<agentname>john</agentname> \n";
$outtext .= "<agentphone>123</agentphone> \n";
foreach ($result->property as $oneproperty)
{
$propertyname = $oneproperty->propertyname;
outtext .= '<property><postcode> $arow["pCode"] </postcode>
<price> $arow["price"]</price> <imagefile> $arow["iFile"] </imagefile> <visits>
$arow["visits"] 
</visits>    </property> \n';
}
$outtex .= "</estateagent>";
fwrite($outfilepointer, $outtext);
fclose($outfilepointer);
sqlite_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

This is what my output should be...

```
<estateagent>
<agentname></agentname>
<agentphone></agentphone>
<property>
<postcode></postcode><price></price><imagefile></imagefile><visits></visits>
</property>
<property>...</property>
<property>...</property>
</estateagent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried using your code and the XML tags do show up. Try opening it in notepad to see.

As for your foreach loop, you need to concatenate your strings.

```
outtext .= '<property><postcode> $arow["pCode"] </postcode> 
<price> $arow["price"]</price> <imagefile> $arow["iFile"] </imagefile> <visits> 
$arow["visits"]  
</visits>    </property> \n';
```

For the foreach, my understanding is that `sqlite_fetch_all` returns an array. You are treating it as a variable.

Try using: `foreach ($result as $oneproperty)`. As I am not sure how your database is structured, if that does not work for you, post the output of `$result` using `var_dump($result)`.

The above means that the literal string will be outputted and no variables will be inserted. You need to do this:

```
outtext .= '<property><postcode>'. $arow["pCode"]. '</postcode> 
<price>'. $arow["price"].'</price> <imagefile>'. $arow["iFile"].' </imagefile> <visits>'. 
$arow["visits"].'
</visits>    </property> \n';
```

Finally, instead of creating your tags manually with strings, consider using the [XML Writer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php).

Comment: still getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..."

Comment: Edited my answer to give a possible solution for that.